# Restrict Django admin action to one checked object

Tags: django, checkbox, action, admin

I have an admin form that allows for objects to be selected via checkbox and a drop-down custom action to export object to CSV.

By default this also comes with a drop-down action to delete multiple selected objects.

I was wondering if there was a way to keep the multiple object delete functionality, but have a message pop up restricting the user from exporting more than one object to CSV at a time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

```
def export_to_csv(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    if queryset.count() != 1:
        modeladmin.message_user(request, "Can not export more than one object to csv at once.")
        return

    # your logic here
```